# How do I redirect users to a different path upon signing in? (with Devise)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'd like to re-direct my users to their dashboard path when signing in, instead of the just re-loading the current page as a "signed-in" user. I've looked over the Devise docs and they only seem to show how to re-direct users to the current page?

How can I re-direct them to the user_dashboard_path?

Thanks!

Comment: i suggest you read [Devise#How-To](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-Tos)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    'any_url' || 'any_path' 
  end
end
```

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in

Answer (score 1):

Look a little harder :)

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in

In your ApplicationController

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  user_dashboard_path
end
```